# Is it guaranteed that Svelte's onMount() is called once in production?

Tags: javascript, svelte, lifecycle

Given that `onMount()` of Svelte is a [lifecycle function](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount), it seems that `onMount()` is called once for each component.

However, I found that `onMount()` is called whenever I modify the code in Svelte REPL.

For example, if you modify the code in [Svelte MathJax REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ebd12dbf04574b2bb40003cc8a4299b0?version=3.14.1),
and open the inspector of the browser,
you will find *several* scripts of the same src attribute are added to the DOM.

[image: example image]

Does this only happen in REPL, or also in the production version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the REPL everytime you modify the code the component is re-mounted because it has changed and should now show a different component.

In a production app this will not happen because you are not changing the code anymore.  It will however be called *once* per instance of this component:

```html
<Component />
<Component />
<Component />
<Component />
```

the above code would fire the `onMount` in `Component` **4 times** because you have 4 instances of it.